# How to calculate returning users in Power Pivot using DAX?

Tags: excel, pivot, dax

I have several tables in Excel using Power Pivot:

1. A daily betting amount report, which includes the date, user name, and betting amount.
2. A user list, which includes the user name (unique) and the user registration date.
3. An agent list, which includes the user name and superior (unique user).
4. A calendar generated by Power Pivot, which is linked to the date in the daily betting amount report.

I want to calculate the number of users lost each month and display the number of users lost each month in the pivot report. A user is considered lost if they have not bet for more than 30 days.

Additionally, if a user does not bet for 30 days but then returns to bet, I need another calculation for returning users.

I need these calculations to be responsive to date and agent filters in the pivot report. That is, when I change the date or agent filter, the number of lost and returning users should update accordingly.

I am using Excel 365 and Power Pivot. How can I achieve this using DAX?"

I have tried to calculate the number of returning users with a DAX formula that checks for each user if they have a bet in the last 30 days and if their previous bet was more than 30 days before the last bet.

Here is the DAX formula I used:

```
Returning Users :=
VAR CurrentDate = MAX ( 'Calendar'[Date] )
RETURN
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( '新注册用户New user'[用户名称] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( '新注册用户New user'[用户名称] ),
        VAR LastBetDate = CALCULATE (
            MAX ( '三方日常投注额 日期 Third party betting  by date by website'[日期] ),
            ALL ( '三方日常投注额 日期 Third party betting  by date by website' )
        )
        VAR SecondLastBetDate = CALCULATE (
            MAX ( '三方日常投注额 日期 Third party betting  by date by website'[日期] ),
            ALL ( '三方日常投注额 日期 Third party betting  by date by website' ),
            '三方日常投注额 日期 Third party betting  by date by website'[日期] < LastBetDate
        )
        RETURN
        LastBetDate <= CurrentDate && LastBetDate > CurrentDate - 30
            && SecondLastBetDate <= CurrentDate - 30
    )
)
```

Comment: Ferrari & Russo wrote an article about it on their website, DAXPatterns.com  - I'd just follow their example.

https://www.daxpatterns.com/new-and-returning-customers/

Comment: This one is totally what i want 
thanks so much